# Cannot run SqLite in method();

Tags: java, android, windows, oop

I am having this unknown problem i just cant solve the problem is that when i retrieve values from sqlite in android its works fine i did the same thing in two classes its all fine does what i want it to do but when i do this in a method it does not work its gives my a null pointer exception it works every where except in method when i pass parameter in my method it gives error and my app closes.

My database works here

```
public class Activity5 extends Activity {
public  static String  tableler; 
final Context cont = this;
static String a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8;
static String out,out2,out3,out4,out5,out6,out7,out8;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity5);
    final EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.replayedit);
    Button btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveChange);
   Button btncancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
   SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("ComDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT REPLAYS FROM Rtm WHERE ID = "+Activity3.replays, null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  out = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("REPLAYS"));

   db.close();

   c.close();
   if(Activity3.replays.contains("1"))
   {

       edt.setText("great"+out);
   }if(Activity3.replays.contains("2"))
   {

       edt.setText("great"+out);
   }if(Activity3.replays.contains("3"))
   {

       edt.setText("great"+out);
   }if(Activity3.replays.contains("4"))
   {

       edt.setText("great"+out);
   }if(Activity3.replays.contains("5"))
   {

       edt.setText("great"+out);
   }if(Activity3.replays.contains("6"))
   {

       edt.setText("great"+out);
   }if(Activity3.replays.contains("7"))
   {

       edt.setText("great"+out);
   }if(Activity3.replays.contains("8"))
   {

       edt.setText("great"+out);
   }


  // this.vieww();
  // this.edit();

   btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String updates = edt.getText().toString();
    updater(Activity3.replays, updates);
        Toast.makeText(cont, "Your Implementation   complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
});



btncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});   





}


    public void updater(String sid,String vals)
{

    String tableNb = "REPLAYS";
    String tablela = "Rtm";
    String ID = "ID";
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("ComDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);  
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(tableNb, vals);

    db.update(tablela, cv, ID+"="+sid, null);
//  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT REPLAYS FROM Rtm WHE", selectionArgs)

    db.close();


}



    }
```

it gives error here and closes my app

```
public class SendGlass extends Activity{

      static String replay;





       public void sms (String phone,String Sms )
{

    SmsManager  smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    String phoneNo = phone;
    String sms = Sms;
    String api = "You Entered one";
    String api2 = "You Entered two";
    String api3 = "Nothing great";
    String rep = sms.replace(phoneNo+" :", "");



    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("ComDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT REPLAYS FROM Rtm WHERE ID = 1", null);

    while(c.moveToNext())

    {
        replay = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("REPLAYS"));

        if(rep.equals("1"))
        {

    //  String replay = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("REPLAYS"));
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);

        }if(rep.equals("2"))
        {


        //  String replay = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("REPLAYS"));
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
        }if(rep.equals("3"))
        {

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
        }if(rep.equals("4"))
        {

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
        }if(rep.equals("5"))
        {

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
        }if(rep.equals("6"))
        {

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
        }if(rep.equals("7"))
        {

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
        }if(rep.equals("8"))
        {

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, replay, null, null);
        }
    }

}
```

My BroadCast class from where i get parameter for my sendGlass

```
public class BroadCastRecivers extends BroadcastReceiver{

static String from;
static String body;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context cont, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method 

//  SmsManager  smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();


        // TODO Auto-generated method s
          //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
             from =   str +=  "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();              
                str += " :";
           body =  str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";

            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(cont, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // ret = str;
            //   int tos =  Integer.valueOf(body);
             //  obj.Decision(from, tos);
          // sms(from, body);     
        //    String phoneNo = phone;
        //  String sms = Sms;

        //  SmsManager  smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        //  smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);   


    /**      Activity5 obj = new Activity5();
          String rep = body.replace("from"+" :", "");

          if(rep.equals("1"))
          {
              Activity3.replays = rep;
              obj.select(from, rep);
          }if(rep.equals("2"))
          {
              Activity3.replays = rep;
              obj.select(from, rep);
          }if(rep.equals("3"))
          {
              Activity3.replays = rep;
              obj.select(from, rep);
          }if(rep.equals("4"))
          {
              Activity3.replays = rep;
              obj.select(from, rep);
          }if(rep.equals("5"))
          {
              Activity3.replays = rep;
              obj.select(from, rep);
          }if(rep.equals("6"))
          {
              Activity3.replays = rep;
              obj.select(from, rep);
          }if(rep.equals("7"))
          {
              Activity3.replays = rep;
              obj.select(from, rep);
          }if(rep.equals("8"))
          {

             Activity3.replays = rep;
             obj.select(from, rep);
          }else
          {
              rep = "Sorry man";
                 obj.select(from, rep);

          }

          **/


                from = "somehing";
                body = "exception";
                SendGlass obj = new SendGlass();
              obj.sms(from, body);
```

}
    }

My logCat.

```
  12-05 23:37:38.507: D/AndroidRuntime(267): Shutting down VM
  12-05 23:37:38.507: W/dalvikvm(267): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
  12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver automator.mator.BroadCastRecivers: java.lang.NullPointerException
  12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
  12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
  12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
  12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at automator.mator.SendGlass.<init>(SendGlass.java:12)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at automator.mator.BroadCastRecivers.onReceive(BroadCastRecivers.java:100)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
   12-05 23:37:38.597: E/AndroidRuntime(267):   ... 10 more
   12-05 23:37:43.027: I/Process(267): Sending signal. PID: 267 SIG: 9
```

my the method works if i use hardcoded string it only gives error when getting values from database.

Comment: what is the 12th line in SendGlass  class?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used any of the Activity methods in SendGlass...

- You *must* launch an Activity by calling `startActivity(Intent)`
- You *must* wait until `onCreate()` is called before you can work with the Activity's Context
- You cannot call `sms()` with `new SendGlass().sms(phone, sms)`

Otherwise you'll see these NullPointerExceptions being thrown in the ContextWrapper class.

For example, `SendGlass` should look more like this:

```
public class SendGlass extends Activity{
    static String replay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null) {
            sms(intent.getStringExtra("phone", ""), intent.getStringExtra("sms", ""));
        }
    }
    ...
```

---

**Addition**
I see that you added you BroadcastReceiver code. Like I guessed you are trying to launch your Activity with:

```
SendGlass obj = new SendGlass();
obj.sms(from, body);
```

As I said, you **must** use Intents and `startActivity()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(cont, SendGlass.class);
intent.putExtra("phone", from);
intent.putExtra("sms", body);
cont.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how am i suppose to implement it i am getting parameter from a class

Comment: If you are asking how to pass your two String Parameters, you should pass the inside the Intent with `putExtra()` and read them like I have shown.

Comment: Do you need to extend the Activity class? If you aren't going to use any of the Activity's methods, change the declaration to `public class SendGlass {` and pass a valid Context in a Constructor `public SendGlass(Context context) {`.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to openOrCreateDatabase() looks screwed up. I don't see any signature for that method that uses those types. What I see in the javadoc are these three signatures:

- openOrCreateDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
- openOrCreateDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
- openOrCreateDatabase(File file, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)

None of these match your usage, which seems to be 
openOrCreateDatabase(path path, int mode, Object)

I also notice that you're trying to use the database variable "db" without first checking to see that it contains something. This is not good programming practice. I never assume that a file or database open has worked; one never knows.

In addition, you're trying to call c.moveToNext() on a Cursor "c" without first validating that c exists and contains a row. That's *definitely* not good programming practice. *Always* test that c != null, and also test c.moveToFirst == true. This ensures that the database call worked (that is, it didn't return null) and that you got back rows (c.MoveToFirst works).

Comment: You are looking in the wrong class, the LogCat shows that the code steps into [`ContextWrapper#openOrCreateDatabase()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String%2Cint%2Candroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29) just fine. The problem is that `mBase`, the Activity's Context, is null.